# Как создать наследника игрока?

Tags: ооп, javascript

```
var Game = function(){

    var game = this;

    game.Player = {
        pts:[]
    }

   }
```

Как создать наследника игрока в этом же классе/объекте? Напр.

```
game.Computer extends game.Player?
```

надеюсь все понятно.

`[updated]`

```
var Game = function(){

    var game = this;

    game.Player = {
        pts:[],
        test: function(){ alert('test'); }
    }

    Player.prototype = new Computer;

    game.Computer = {

    }
}

var game = new Game();

game.Computer.test();
```

Вариант со стека мне посоветовали сделать `prototype`, но как бы я его ни лепил...

или даже так:

```
var Game = function(){

    var game = this;

    game.Player = {
        pts:[],
        test: function(){ alert('test'); }
    }

    game.Player.prototype = game.Computer {

    }

}

var game = new Game();

game.Computer.test();
```

Что тоже не верно как оказывается.

Comment: а где определение Computer ?

Answer (score 1):

кажется вам хочется странного, примерно такого:

```
var Game = function(){
    var game = this;

    Player.prototype.pts=[];
    Player.prototype.test=function(){ console.log('test'); };

    Computer.prototype = new Player();
    game.Player=new Player();
    game.Computer=new Computer();
    function Computer() {}
    function Player() {}

};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/yeDey/